# Convert row value in to column in SQL server (PIVOT)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have table in SQL Server called **test** having 3 column

```
|  ITEM | ATTRIBUTE | VALUE |
-----------------------------
| item1 |   Quality |     A |
| item1 |     color |   Red |
| item2 |   Quality |     B |
| item2 |     color | Black |
```

I want output like this:

```
|  ITEM | QUALITY | COLOR |
---------------------------
| item1 |       A |   Red |
| item2 |       B | Black |
```

How can I get this in SQL Server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Item, attribute, value FROM MyTable) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value)
  FOR attribute IN([Quality], [Color])
) AS p;
```

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ ITEM  ║ QUALITY ║ COLOR ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ item1 ║ A       ║ Red   ║
║ item2 ║ B       ║ Black ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b315/1)

You can also use this dynamic query if you don't know the specific value of `attribute`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(attribute) 
                    from MyTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Item,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                Select Item, attribute , value
                from MyTable
             ) dta
             pivot 
             (
                MAX(Value)
                for attribute in (' + @cols + ')
             ) pvt '

execute(@query);
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b315/3)

Comment: in this case its only giving max value Ex item1  NULL RED

Comment: Item2   B   NULL   because of max function

Comment: @Dilip - Did you see the result in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b50/1)

Comment: @Dilip - What? Then what's the problem? In the fiddle NULL is not coming.. Are you trying something else?

Comment: oh sorry ,, yes its working ust i change some data , thts why problem was coming .. Thanks .

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a hacky solution for mysql as PIVOT doesn't work in it.

```
select item, GROUP_CONCAT('',q) as Quantity, GROUP_CONCAT('',c) as Color from 
(select item ,CASE WHEN attribute = 'Quality' THEN value ELSE NULL END as q, CASE WHEN attribute = 'Color' THEN value ELSE NULL END as c 
 from MyTable
) temp 
group by item
```

Issue with this solution is that you should know all the distinct values of attribute column.

You can try it [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9caf/5)

Comment: Thanks for your solution!

You can use this [guide](https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/#:~:text=To%20achieve%20this%20in%20dbForge,of%20which%20will%20be%20rows.)
to solve the issue with this solution, and build dynamic query (:

Answer (score 0):

String Aggregation can be used as well,

```
SELECT item, STRING_AGG(CAST(q AS STRING)) AS Quantity, STRING_AGG(CAST(c AS STRING)) AS Color
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      item,
      CASE WHEN attribute = 'Quality' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS q,
      CASE WHEN attribute = 'Color' THEN value ELSE NULL END AS c
    FROM MyTable
  ) temp
GROUP BY item
```