# Convert enumerated type and corresponding values into separate column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would not be surprised if this is a duplicate, but I have not been able to find this variation on the theme.

I have a table with two columns: one indicates data type, and the other the corresponding value. I want to convert this using SELECT so that each enumerated "type" is its own column populated by the values.

```
Table PersonInfo
InfoID    PersonID    AttributeType    AttributeValue
     1           1         email       bob@example.com
     2           1         dept        research
     3           2         email       judy@example.com
     4           2         dept        engineering
     5           3         email       frank@example.com
```

The SELECT result will be:

```
PersonID    email              dept
       1    bob@example.com    research
       2    judy@example.com   engineering
       3    frank@example.com  NULL
```

As you can see, the InfoID index is no longer needed.

In my case, I know the potential values in the AttributeType column, so I don't need it to be completely dynamic.

Here is what I tried:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, 
        CASE AttributeType WHEN 'email' THEN AttributeValue ELSE null END as email
        CASE AttributeType WHEN 'dept' THEN AttributeValue ELSE null END as dept
```

I know why this is failing, but I'm not sure what to do to get it to work as I would like.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to break out email and department into separate columns.  A column that serves more than one purpose is often hard to work with.  Appreciate you may not be able to change the database design.

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916470/convert-row-value-in-to-column-in-sql-server-pivot appears to do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
personid,
max(case when attributetype='email' then AttributeValue end) email,
max(case when attributetype='dept' then AttributeValue end) dept
from
table
group by personid
```