# Converting 200+ rows to column in SQL Server using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have done some research and so far, this one makes sense to me:

[Convert row value in to column in SQL server (PIVOT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916470/convert-row-value-in-to-column-in-sql-server-pivot)

However, I am wondering if there is any way to do this without having to declare the needed columns one by one, as I have more than 200 columns to retrieve.

Here's a sneak peek of what I have as a table:

```
ID   | Col_Name   | Col_Value    
------------------------------
1    | Item_Num   | 12345
2    | Item_Date  | 34567
3    | Item_Name  | 97454
4    | Item_App1  | 234567
5    | Item_App2  | 345678
```

Take note that I have 200+ distinct values for Col_Name and I want it to be Column fields.

I am using this one as of now but only for 5 columns:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT [ID], [Col_Name], [Col_Value] 
   FROM myTable
) AS a 
PIVOT 
(
   MAX([Col_Value])
   FOR [Col_Name] in ([Item_Num], [Item_Date], [Item_Name], [Item_App1], [Item_App2])
) AS p 
ORDER BY [ID]
```

Is there any way this could be done considering the performance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fd3c90a-895f-4a37-8804-75a092ca0807/performance-of-sql-pivot-query-against-large-tables?forum=transactsql

Comment: If you care about performance, don't store your data in this format.  Just use a regular record with 200+ columns, one for each column.

Comment: This is just one of the many problems you will enjoy using a EAV design. In fact, you have already provided one in your sample data - 34567 is a valid "date" in your table because the column will allow this value to be stored as such.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have to use this format as per requirement at work.

Comment: @SMor Agree on EAV. As for the sample data I posted, apologies for the confusion. This is not the exact data for my table, I just typed whatever it is there you see just to show an example. Also, the whole table has values all in nvarchar datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to create the list of col_name:

```
declare @pivot_col varchar(max);
declare @sql       varchar(max);
select  @pivot_col = string_agg( cast(col_name as varchar(max)), ', ') within group ( order by col_name ) from ( select distinct col_name from tmp_table ) A;

set @sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM   (
                      SELECT [ID], [Col_Name], [Col_Value] 
                      FROM tmp_table
                   ) AS a 
                   PIVOT 
                   (
                      MAX([Col_Value])
                      FOR [Col_Name] in (' +  @pivot_col + ' )
                   ) AS p 
                   ORDER BY [ID]';
exec ( @sql );
```

The PIVOT / UNPIVOT operators are built on the principles of an Entity Attribute Value model (EAV). The idea behind an EAV model is that you can extend database entities without performing database schema changes. For that reason an EAV model stores all attributes of an entity in one table as key/value pairs.

If that is the idea behind your design then use the dynamic sql query i posted above, otherwise use a regular record with 200+ columns for each id, as suggested by Gordon.

You can read about the performance of PIVOT / UNPIVOT operators [here](https://sqlsunday.com/2016/01/29/pivot-unpivot-and-performance/).

EDIT:
For sql server 2016 version:

```
declare @pivot_col varchar(max);
declare @sql       varchar(max);
select  @pivot_col = STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CAST(col_name AS VARCHAR(max)) AS [text()] FROM ( select distinct col_name from tmp_table ) A ORDER BY col_name FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL);

set @sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM   ( SELECT [ID], [Col_Name], [Col_Value] 
                     FROM tmp_table
                   ) AS a 
                   PIVOT 
                   (
                      MAX([Col_Value])
                      FOR [Col_Name] in (' +  @pivot_col + ' )
                   ) AS p 
                   ORDER BY [ID]';
exec ( @sql );
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed info. However, I am using Sql Server 2016 and I'm afraid that sting_agg is causing an error here. 

   `'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.` 

I'm also looking into the link you shared, thanks so much.

Comment: You can use FOR XML PATH as a replacement of string_agg function. I have edited my answer to include the new query. Hope it helps

Comment: I was actually playing with that since yesterday, but you made it really easy in one line! Thanks so much. This is what I was looking for. I would have to go over the performance though, as it took almost 30mins for the query to finish executing. I am only returning 800+ rows, so it seems like the 230 columns made it very slow.

Comment: Hi Mohit, just in case you have time to look into this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58949146/will-the-use-of-cursor-improve-the-performance-speed-of-querying-using-pivot-i Thanks!

Comment: How can you handle more than 200+ columns using this approach? I think there are character limitations when you declare varchar(max)