# Will the use of CURSOR improve the performance / speed of querying using PIVOT in SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot-table, sql-server-2016

Newbie here on **EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) model** of DB in SQL.

Just a background: I am using *SQL Server 2016*. The use of EAV is kind of a requirement at work so I am learning to do it one step at a time.

I recently learned how to do a dynamic **PIVOT** to return **800+ rows** with **200+ columns** in an EAV table.

See details here:
[Converting 200+ rows to column in SQL Server using PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912797/converting-200-rows-to-column-in-sql-server-using-pivot)

As successful it was to return the data I need, the performance speed was too slow - it took about 30mins to query. By the way, I am using the code as follows:

```
declare @pivot_col varchar(max);
declare @sql varchar(max);

select @pivot_col = STUFF( 
                             ( SELECT ',' + CAST([Col_Name] AS VARCHAR(max) ) AS [text()]  
                             FROM ( select distinct [Col_Name] from tbl_Values ) A 
                             ORDER BY [Col_Name] FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL
                          );

set @sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM ( SELECT [Row_ID], [Col_Name], [Col_Value] FROM tbl_Values ) AS a 
            PIVOT (
                    MAX([Col_Value])
                    FOR [Col_Name] in (' +  @pivot_col + ' )
                  ) AS p 
            ORDER BY [Row_ID]';

exec ( @sql );
```

I am trying to incorporate **CURSOR** with this but hasn't gone much far. Before I go more distance on research, can you provide input as to if it makes any difference with regards to performance / speed?

Thanks!

Comment: This is of course one of the downsides of EAV. A cursor will likely be slower. You don't have any predicates or joins (where clause) on your query so there's not much you can do.

Comment: Perhaps you can start by making a clustered index on row_id column. The pivot operator, be default, groups by on the column which is not used inside the PIVOT, so the index might be a little help

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for the input. This has been the challenge since I started with EAV.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava You should put this as answer! I literally jumped out of my seat when my query returned 800+ rows and 200+ columns in 6 seconds after creating the clustered index. I read a few articles on this and clustered indexes really made a dramatic improvement in performance for EAV tables.

Comment: clustered indexes make an improvement for any table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I agree! Same happened to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to the poor performance of my PIVOT query: I was told to create a clustered index on the Row_ID column I have in my table. I ran the query below:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_tbl_Values_Row_ID  
ON dbo.tbl_Values (Row_ID);   
GO
```

And the query I have on my question which took 30 mins to load before had now run for just 6 seconds now! Thanks to @MohitShrivastava for the tip! Definitely worked.

I also referred to this before creating the clustered index: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15